# Is it possible to overuse chkdsk?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

I perform a `chkdsk /f/v/sdcleanup/perf/scan` every time I use an external USB drive or hard disk drive — and on my internal drives — every time I copy or delete a big file (size more than 1GB) only to find on [this page](https://silicophilic.com/reparse-records-processed/) that “…it is not advised to perform this operation frequently.”

I understand that using the `/r` switch is bad for a hard disk drive and SSDs as well since it involves writing, reading than deleting files, but other than that in what form would my command harm my disks?

Edit: I live in a place with a lot of electric power instabilities.

Comment: “…every time I copy or delete a big file…” Why do you do this to begin with? Why do you think copying a “big file” leads to disk damage? And why do you think you have to do this all the time instead of just letting the system do what it does? It’s kind of like taking an Aspirin every time you have a very big thought to preemptively avoid getting a headache.

Answer (score 2):

### Don’t use disk repair tools if you don’t have to.

#### It is a wasted effort at best and you will put the disks under an additional strain at worst.

You say this about your use of `chkdsk`:

> “…every time I copy or delete a big file…”

Why do you do this to begin with? Why do you think copying a “big file” leads to disk damage? And why do you think you have to do this all the time instead of just letting the system do what it does? It’s kind of like taking an Aspirin every time you have a very big thought to preemptively avoid getting a headache.

While I do not use Windows — macOS and Linux on my side — there is some fundamental logic here: Any time you use disk repair software, the system needs to go through the whole file system to check for damage. Even if there is no damage whatsoever, the drive still needs to be read from. And if you do this every time a “big file” is copied, you are putting the drive under 2x the usage that is needed for a file copy.

Now is this bad? Debatable. Modern drives are typically designed to deal with usage better than nowadays than in the past. But it is a waste of time at best. It is giving you false assurance when the fact the file copied at all — without errors — should be assurance enough that is is fine.

I recommend you only run any disk repair tool if there is a good reason. Such as a sudden shutdown or abrupt dismount or accidentally dropping it on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to overuse chkdsk.

Chkdsk is a dangerous operation for two reasons:

1. It is heavy on I/O and so places an additional burden on the disk,
2. If an error is found, chkdsk may fix it in a way that destroys
   one or more files.

For the second case, it is recommended to do chkdsk twice,
and only use the `/f` (fix) parameter on the second try,
and then only if the first one found any errors,
and especially only after doing a *complete backup* of the disk in question.

Your disk will only have errors after a catastrophic failure, such as power down
in the middle of an operation, although modern disks (and especially SSDs)
are less vulnerable to that.

There is nothing wrong with doing a chkdsk occasionally,
if the health of the disk is important to you,
and if you keep to my above recommendation.
Doing so after every use is an overkill that will only shorten
the life-time of the disk.

Comment: Is monitoring S.M.A.R.T a good alternative?

Comment: SMART and xhkdsk are orthogonal. SMART works at a low level and has no knowledge of filesystem's. Xhkdsk works on filesystem's and has no knowledge of the backing device.

Comment: @user10191234 While what David2Go states is correct, the reality is SMART works great at a low level. It will let you know when blocks are failing and the more they fail the more the drive is at risk of failing entirely. But the question is if it is possible to overuse a disk utility and the reality is this: Modern filesystems check their own integrity regularly. Files copied from one drive to another are checked in the copying process. Running a disk utility regular copying a “large file” is overkill at best. This is the year 2020, not 1990. Disks are far more reliable nowadays.

Comment: @user10191234: S.M.A.R.T is not an alternative, but it's a good idea. There exist products that monitor it constantly and raise the alarm in case of a degradation.